# Juniper SRX345 goes into Recovery Mode on power failure; doesn't come all the way up

Tags: juniper, srx, reboot

So we just purchased and installed a Juniper SRX345 as the edge device for our office network.  For various reasons, the power in our office periodically goes down for longer than our 2 minutes of UPS time lasts us, sometimes at night.

Unfortunately when power is restored, the SRX doesn't come all the way up but goes into some kind of recovery mode.  From there I need to physically visit the server room and restart it myself (usually by pulling the plug, plugging it back in, and hitting the power button; once it has already been in recovery mode it comes up normally).

I called Juniper support and they said the recovery mode is a design feature of the device and that if you want to remove power and have it come up right, you need to halt the system in the software first.  In that case, however, you have to hit the power button to get it to start up.

What I'm really looking for is unattended startup after power is restored.  Both of these methods require a personal visit to the office just so our phone menu tree works overnight.

All the Cisco hardware we have installed comes up automatically after a power failure, all of my Dell servers have been configured to do the same.  Is there a way to make this happen for the Juniper SRX345?

Comment: You might hit a better audience at the [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Nice!  How long has that been around?